# Identifying the first element that belongs to different sequences in an array

Tags: python, numpy, grouping, unique, sequence

I have an array (A) of sorted integers which contains ascending sequences with gaps.

`A = array([1,2,3,4, 7,8,9, 23,24,25, 100])`

I have an array (B) that contains a few values selected from A through an external process.

`B = array([1,2,23,25,100])`

I want to filter out values in B that belong to the same sequence in A so it returns only the first values of each unique sequence

`C = array([1,23,100])`

I have managed to do it by creating a second list to keep track of what has already been appended, but it seems kind of clumsy. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,2,3,4, 7,8,9, 23,24,25, 100])
B = np.array([1,2,23,25,100])
C = []

already_used_sequence = []

for x in enumerate(A):
    if x[0]-x[1] in already_used_sequence : #did we already group this sequence?
        pass
    elif len(np.intersect1d(B, x[1])) is not None: #is this value in B?
        for h in B:
            if h == x[1]: 
                C.append(x[1])
                already_used_sequence.append(x[0]-x[1])
C=np.array(C)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a groupby operation, which is not easily done with numpy. One option would be to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

# convert to pandas Series
s = pd.Series(A)

# group by successive values
# keep the first found value per group
out = s[np.isin(A, B)].groupby(s.diff().gt(1).cumsum()).first().to_numpy()
```

Output: `array([  1,  23, 100])`

Answer (score 1):

Some things to point out. First, try using

```
for i, n in enumerate(my_iter):
```

instead of just one variable, then having to access the position and value with indexes.

Also, the len() of the intersection1d will never be None, since if it isn't in the B array the length will be 0, and not None. And you don't have to check for for intersection since you will be passing through the array anyway.

Taking all of this into account and adding a break statement after you found the number it should look like this

```
for i, n in enumerate(A):
if i-n not in already_used_sequence :
    for h in B:
        if h == n: 
            C.append(n)
            already_used_sequence.add(i-n)
            break
```

I changed the already_used_sequence to a set(), that wont make any difference in this small input but its faster then a list in this context when you scale.

If you can guarantee that B will also be in ascending order, you can also do

```
cur_index = 0
for i, n in enumerate(A):
    if n == B[cur_index]:
        cur_index += 1
        if i-n not in already_used_sequence:
            C.append(n)
            already_used_sequence.add(i-n)
```

which is a great speed up at larger inputs since you wont be looping through B every time you need to find a number